# Getting ``DeadlineExceededError'' using GAE when doing many (~10K) DB updates

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using Django 1.4 on GAE + Google Cloud SQL - my code works perfectly fine (on dev with local sqlite3 db for Django) but chocks with Server Error (500) when I try to "refresh" DB. This involves parsing certain files and creating ~10K records and saving them (I'm saving them in batch using commit_on_success).

Any advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is raised for front end requests after 60 seconds. ([its increased](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors))

Solution options:

1. Use [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) (again a time limit of 10 minutes is imposed, which is practically enough).
2. Divide your task in smaller batches. 
   How we do it: we divide it on client side in smaller chunks and call them repeatedly.

Both the solutions work fine, depends on how you make these calls and want the results. Taskqueue doesn't return back the results to the client.

Answer (score 0):

For tasks that take longer than 30s you should use [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/).

Also, database operations can also timeout when batch operations are too big. Try to use smaller batches.

Answer (score -1):

Google app engine has a maximum time allowed for a request. If a request takes longer than 30 seconds, this error is raised. If you have a large quantity of data to upload, either import it directly from the admin console, or break up the request into smaller chunks, or use the command line `python manage.py dbshell` to upload the data from your computer.